# JavaFx Children alignment between 2 HBoxes

Tags: javafx, alignment, hbox

Trying to align children(labels) of 2 different HBoxes, which was created by the same method:

```
public HBox addHBox() {
    HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
    hbox.setLayoutX(10);
    hbox.setPrefWidth(Pane.getWidth());
    hbox.setPrefHeight(Pane.getHeight());
    return hbox;
}
```

The LayoutY is different, and changed after the creation of each HBox.
Thus, I want to accompish that added child[i] of the HBox1, would be right below child[i] of the HBox2.

Note: the size of the children should not matter!
[(this is what bothers me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwl9g.png)

I tried

```
hbox2.setMinWidth(hbox1.getMinWidth());
```

and

```
hbox2.setPrefWidth(hbox1.getPrefWidth());
```

and

```
hbox2.setMaxWidth(hbox1.getMaxWidth());
```

Nothing seems to help. Any ideas?
P.S. I know that i can use gridPane, but it's not in this case

Comment: Do you want to place HBox2 beneath HBox1?

Comment: To clarify: You're using `Text`s not `Label`s? Furthermore why no `GridPane`? Using `HBox`es seems to be incredibly cumbersome. Also why do you expect setting the preferred size would make the children align?

Comment: my mistake,it is labels ofcourse

Comment: Could you also tell us the reason why you do not want to use a `GridPane`? If you e.g. want seperate lists for the children, there is probably a way to make this work with a `GridPane`.

Comment: To manage this in two `HBox`es you would need to control the widths of the individual child nodes of each `HBox`, not the width of the `HBox`es themselves. An `HBox` simply arranges its child nodes left to right, so the position of child `i+1` is simply the position of child `i` plus the width of child `i` (plus spacing, if any). So your assertion that "The size of the children should not matter" is clearly not true: the size of the children is exactly what determines the location of the (other) children. It would be very difficult to do this in `HBox`es: this is what a `GridPane` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HBox` only classifies your `Nodes` one side of the other horizontally, and in your case I suppose that you use a `Text` control to display your String, I don't say that it is a bad idea but I think that the **width** of your `Node`(**`Text`**) depends on the length of the string which gives an unpredictable and disorderly display, so why not use a `Label`, the advantage with this control is that you can define the **Width of the background** what Will give your String a limit and allow an ordered display !

Comment: changed to children(labels). was mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after additional research AND help of the community:

1.Definately should use gridPane.

2.Or change the layoutX of each label in HBox2 to fit layoutX of label from HBox1.